# Upload File to EC2 instance or to S3

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using EC2 instance and S3 buckets for my application. In the app, clients can upload images and these images are put on a canvas. After, the client quit the app, i'm done with these images so they can be deleted.

Firstly, in my design, clients upload image via web form and it goes to EC2 instance and EC2 instace upload it to S3 bucket and return S3 url. So, in this design file is uploaded twice and i think it will not be efficient if EC2 -> S3 upload is not very fast.

If i choose not to save them in S3 and return a url directly points to EC2 instance, the images will stay in EC2 Volume and i will not delete them as easy as S3 rules. May be i will need to delete them manually and it's not reasonable.

So what do you advice, which design i should choose.

Hope i'm clear.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are valid, and it depends what tradeoffs are most important.

S3 is an extra step, if you are using a single instance, you probably don't need it. If you plan to scale, your life will be easier using s3. When you add more instances you wont need to worry about ensuring the user requests go back to the same instance.